# SSL registered under main domain , can we use for subdomain?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Im working with mobile site and i want this site use https, so i have 2 Domain here :

```
www.youbeli.com (Main site)
m.youbeli.com (Mobile site)
```

Then i set `m.youbeli.com` with https , when i browse using my phone(Android) , i found error is pop up

```
Security Warning
There are problems with the security certificate for this site
```

When i view the certificate (below is the information),  :

```
Issued to :
Common name:
www.youbeli.com

Organisational Unit:
GTxxxxxxxxxx
```

So,  the question is i need to register SSL to m.youbeli.com or this is my configuration error ?

Comment: if you get wildcard ssl, you can use it for subdomains, otherwise you cannot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificates are designed to authenticate only the domains contained within them. You'll need to either get a SAN certificate that allows multiple domains you specify, or, since this is all under a single primary domain, purchase a wildcard certificate (*.youbeli.com).

Comment: Since these resolve to different IP addresses, you could also just use two different certificates.

Comment: thanks all , i will discuss with my hosting for wild card or two different certificates for this..